# Python: How to generate frequency count for all variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count

I have a dataset of all categorical variables, and I would like to produce  frequency counts for all variables at once.

Supposedly, I'm using the Iris dataset function `df['class'].value_counts()` will only allow me to count for one variable.

To analyze all variables for a dataset consists only categorical variables extracted as a csv through Pandas. I'm thinking extracting only the first row and put in a for loop. To extract the first row from a csv file we convert csv to dataframe by using `data = pd.DataFrame(data)`. However, `data[0]` will generate an error.

What is the most efficient way of producing frequency analysis or bar graphs for all variables?

Sample dataset with categorical variables:

```
   Mary  John   David    Jenny
    a     t       y        n
    a     t       n        y
    a     u       y        y
    a     u       n        y
    a     u       n        n
    b     t       y        n
```

Comment: do you want the counts to be column wise or the entire dataframe

Comment: @RushabhMehta Yes, I'm interested in count by the levels in each variable. Ex: Mary, a:5, b=1.

Comment: Gotchu. Working on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack()
```

Output:

```
Mary   a    5.0
       b    1.0
John   t    3.0
       u    3.0
David  n    3.0
       y    3.0
Jenny  n    3.0
       y    3.0
dtype: float64
```

**Method 2**

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0)
```

Output

```
          a   b   n   t   u   y
Mary    5.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
John    0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 3.0 0.0
David   0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 3.0
Jenny   0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 3.0
```

Then, you can simply use below o create a bar chart.

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T.stack().plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).T.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The second method produces lovely result on my actual dataset, which has over 100k obs. Could you also suggest a way to exclude a variable from the frequency analysis?

Comment: I would suggest you can simply ignore all rows of that variable and apply these method(s).

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=1)
Out[537]: 
       a  b  n  t  u  y
Mary   5  1  0  0  0  0
John   0  0  0  3  3  0
David  0  0  3  0  0  3
Jenny  0  0  3  0  0  3
```

And plot as bar like below

```
df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=1).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: I received an error using str.get_dummies() : `~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in get_dummies(self, sep)
   1695         # methods available for making the dummies...
   1696         data = self._orig.astype(str) if self._is_categorical else self._data
-> 1697         result, name = str_get_dummies(data, sep)
   1698         return self._wrap_result(result, use_codes=(not self._is_categorical),
   1699                                  name=name, expand=True)`

Comment: @lydias first test with your sample data , you provide to us , see whether it is work or not , if it work in your sample data you showed here, but not working on the real data , you should find the different between the data , which means your sample data can not reproduced your problem

Comment: I tried the other methods as well. This is the only that doesn't work on the original dataset.

Comment: @lydias then using another answer , I will not delete it since this is way I usually do for the str type plot , maybe you should do df=df.astype(str) I guess , Still not a very clear question , at least not reproduced your problem

Comment: Note: I tried this solution and it works fine for me. @lydias, may be your minified input data is not a representative of your 100k rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame({i:df[i].value_counts() for i in df.columns})
```

Note: this will produce a run time error if there are a lot of NaNs, but you can ignore these. If you don't like the NaNs, just use

```
{i:df[i].value_counts() for i in df.columns}
```